# Azure Internal Load balancers not using their IP Address to return traffic

Tags: azure, tcp, udp, azure-virtual-network

I have an internal load balancer which is connected to another network via a gateway and IPSEC tunnel.

During test I can receive traffic through the tunnel to it's load-balanced address (10.10.11.4).

However if I sent traffic back (even from the node that received it) the traffic appears with the host IP's NOT the load balancer IP address so further routing goes wrong.

It's designed to be used with UDP but I've tried both UDP and TCP protocols and the behaviour is the same. I've tried looking for documentation around this but I've found nothing, so I'm not what the intended behaviour is ?

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

When you originate a session to the ILB VIP (through the IPSEC tunnel in your case), your session will get mapped to a healthy VM in the pool.  Return traffic within that session should be mapped such as to look like a response from the VIP you attempted to connect.

A session originating from a VM is not address translated to the VIP but instead will use the source address of the VM it originated from.